# I can't convert String Comparison sentence in my Query : msSQL to SQLite

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I use msSQL for my system.

But I need to use Android Database : SQLite.

My Query's purpose is Find Koeran Initial.

In msSQL, string comparsion works.

For test, I maked my Query like this,

```
  select [UserNo],[UserName]
  from 
     (select [UserNo], [UserName], 
      SUBSTRING(replace([UserName], ' ', ''),1,1)[name0],
      SUBSTRING(replace([UserName], ' ', ''),2,1)[name1],
      SUBSTRING(replace([UserName], ' ', ''),3,1)[name2], 
      SUBSTRING(replace([UserName], ' ', ''), 4,1)[name3],
      SUBSTRING(replace([UserName], ' ', ''), 5,1)[name4]
      from Info_User  
      where [UserName] >= 'ㄱ' and [UserName] < 'A') as sub 
  where ([name0] >= 'ㅎ' and [name0] < 'A' and [name1] >= 'ㅈ' and [name1] < 'ㅉ' and [name2] >= 'ㅇ' and [name2] < 'ㅈ')
     or ([name1] >= 'ㅎ' and [name1] < 'A' and [name2] >= 'ㅈ' and [name2] < 'ㅉ' and [name3] >= 'ㅇ' and [name3] < 'ㅈ')
     or ([name2] >= 'ㅎ' and [name2] < 'A' and [name3] >= 'ㅈ' and [name3] < 'ㅉ' and [name4] >= 'ㅇ' and [name4] < 'ㅈ')
  order by [UserName] asc;
```

This truely works very well in msSQL.

My SQL version : Microsoft SQL Server Managemnet Studio 17.

But, as I said in the first time, I need to convert this Query for SQLite.

SQLite has no SUBSTRING, but SUBSTR.

So, I convert my Query like this,

```
  select [UserNo],[UserName]
  from 
     (select [UserNo], [UserName], 
      SUBSTR(replace([UserName], ' ', ''),1,1)[name0],
      SUBSTR(replace([UserName], ' ', ''),2,1)[name1],
      SUBSTR(replace([UserName], ' ', ''),3,1)[name2], 
      SUBSTR(replace([UserName], ' ', ''), 4,1)[name3],
      SUBSTR(replace([UserName], ' ', ''), 5,1)[name4]
      from Info_User  
      where [UserName] >= 'ㄱ' and [UserName] < 'A') as sub 
  where ([name0] >= 'ㅎ' and [name0] < 'A' and [name1] >= 'ㅈ' and [name1] < 'ㅉ' and [name2] >= 'ㅇ' and [name2] < 'ㅈ')
     or ([name1] >= 'ㅎ' and [name1] < 'A' and [name2] >= 'ㅈ' and [name2] < 'ㅉ' and [name3] >= 'ㅇ' and [name3] < 'ㅈ')
     or ([name2] >= 'ㅎ' and [name2] < 'A' and [name3] >= 'ㅈ' and [name3] < 'ㅉ' and [name4] >= 'ㅇ' and [name4] < 'ㅈ')
  order by [UserName] asc;
```

It definitely runs when I debug this, So I think this Query is correct sentence in grammatically.

I think my 'WHERE sentence' is not acceptable in SQLite.

How I could compare string in SQLite?

Comment: In Unicode, what string is going to be less than `A` and greater or equal to any Korean character?

Comment: Unicode int value in Korean character is over 45000.

Comment: @Shawn Oh, Thank God. Your Comment is very helpful for me. 'A' is the lower value in sqlite.